# shell script to extract a string from parameter

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am working on a shell script where it has to extract string from parameter passed. If I am passing parameters like

```
      test.sh arg1=someArgument Arg2=AnoTherArgument
```

Assume user may pass the arguments with the name and value in any case,

I have to extract the parameters and manipulate, some thing like

```
      for arg in "$@"
      do
          if [ lower("${arg}") == "arg1" ] then
                # extract arg1's value and do something
          elif [ lower("${arg}") == "arg2" ] then
                # extract arg2's value and do something
          fi
      done
```

Please help me how can I extract the parameter's value in the same case that was passed?

Comment: It isn't valid POSIX to use `==` inside of `[ ]`; use a single equals sign, `=`, instead. Also, which shell and version are you targeting? bash 4 has parameter expansion operators built-in for converting variables to lower and upper case, without the need for external tools such as tr.

Comment: you should not change your question, because the title would not be coherent, accept the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, I prefer a case statement like this:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
    a=* ) echo ${1#a=};;
    b=* ) echo ${1#b=};;
    # etc
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: I have edited the post. Please have a look. The arguments name passed can be of any type. If so I can convert the argument to lowercase using tr [:upper:] [:lower:], but how can I extract the value of argument with the same case the user has passed ?  Please help me.

Comment: `[Aa][Rr][Gg]1) echo ${1#[Aa][Rr][Gg]1};;`

Comment: Do just the same: convert only the first part of each argument with tr [:upper:] [:lower:], maybe like this (assuming only one equal sign per argument): `case $(echo ${1%=*} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]) in; arg1 ) echo ${1#*=};; ; esac` (Sorry for the bad display)

Answer (score 0):

Use double bracket to match glob pattern ; semicolon is needed before "then"

```
if [[ "$arg" = a=* ]];then echo ${arg#a=};fi
```

or

```
if [ "${arg%%=*}" = a ];then echo ${arg#a=};fi
```

for more information

```
man bash
/Parameter Expansion
```

Comment: I have edited the post. Please have a look. The arguments name passed can be of any type. If so I can convert the argument to lowercase using tr [:upper:] [:lower:], but how can I extract the value of argument with the same case the user has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother working to parse arguments?  Pass things through the environment:

In `foo`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Value of arg1: ${arg1-default value}
```

Then:

```
$ arg1=blah ./foo
Value of arg1: blah
```

and

```
$ ./foo
Value of arg1: default value
```